# Debian have a single source to obtain linux-headers for multiple kernels?

Tags: linux, header, kernel, debian

Does Debian have a site where all the linux-headers are located similar to what Ubuntu has (http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) ?

Basically I need to install a bunch of the linux-headers for various versions to build a module against them.  All from one machine / install.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able extract the different version of headers dirs from the kernel git source tree.

Put them here:

```
/lib/modules/kernel-headers-x.y.z/
```

Then you can build against different headers with this command.

```
make -C /lib/modules/kernel-headers-x.y.z/build M=`pwd` modules
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping kernel.org could be a one stop shop for the headers, but I don't get the way it is set up?   I click browse to go look for the headers but it just brings up changes?   Then all the patches?   Using a web browser, where do I go to get the headers needed to build a module?   (Debian calls the the linux-headers-{KERNELVER}-generic).  Would I have to download the full source, then which folder do I use (any generic one or it's specific?)

Answer (score 0):

- Install from console: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-(version of kernel)`
- Download deb-package from website https://packages.debian.org: [example](https://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64) ( for special version of headers use search ) and [install it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114).